# TikZ Matrix 'draw' alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices

Apologies if this has already been asked - I could not find it.

The following is an example of what goes wrong:
[image]

In this example I would like it to look just like a regular 2x3 table, but I think the problem is that draw starts from the end of the math, not the end of the cell. (I'd prefer to not just use tabular as I will be arrows between columns ultimately)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={anchor=center},text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex,inner sep=2pt,row sep=1.5em,column sep=1.5em,] (M)
{
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a+b+c+d+e & a+b+c+d+e & a+b+c+d+e \\
}    ;
\draw[] (M-1-1.north west) -- (M-1-3.north east);
\draw[] (M-2-1.north west) -- (M-2-3.north east);
\draw[] (M-2-1.south west) -- (M-2-3.south east);
\draw[] (M-1-1.north east) -- (M-2-1.south east);
\draw[] (M-1-2.north east) -- (M-2-2.south east);
\draw[] (M-1-3.north east) -- (M-2-3.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the option `nodes={draw}` option to the matrix you can see the problem clearer.

[image]

The quickest way to fix it is the make the nodes equal size with `text width` option. Regardless of their content.

So using the option `nodes={text width=3cm,align=center,anchor=center}` will give you

[image]

Now you don't need the col sep and row sep or if you do then you can get the midway between two adjacent nodes to draw the rules I would recommend a `\foreach` loop for such cases.